# Restore default Grub text for Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, grub2

I upgraded from Mint 18.3 to Mint 19. I could not boot Mint so I reinstalled Grub with boot-repair (booting from USB). I still could not boot so I disabled Secure Boot (which worked fine under 18.3) and that fixed it.

The problem is the text in my Grub menu refers to Ubuntu not Mint and it looks totally different to how it looked in 18.3. Assuming "Ubuntu" is not the Mint 19 default Grub text, is there a way to restore the text to the Mint defaults?

If the only way is to manually edit the Grub configuration or use grub-customizer, what is the default text that Mint 19 uses for a dual boot system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by running "grub-install /dev/..." and "sudo update-grub" after booting Mint 19. This replaced the changes to the grub menu that boot-repair had made.